# How to get hash value from PBE key generator

Tags: java, encryption, secret-key

I want to use the PBE to generate other encryption keys.

```
public SecretKey generateKey(String Ags) throws Exception {
    // make password
    PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(this.password.toCharArray(),this.salt,20,56);

    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory
            .getInstance("PBE");
    SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    System.out.println();

    /*
    KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    kg.init(k);
    //
    SecretKey FINAL_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), "AES");
    */
    return null;
}
```

My basic idea is use `PBEKeySpec` and `SecretKeyFactory` to generate the PBE key first, and then get the first few bytes, let's say 10 bytes, to generate the AES key. However, after searching the Internet, I still don't know how to get the final key as a `byte[]`. `key.getEncoded()` will just give me the input password. How do I get the final key as a `byte[]`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand by reading the the [documentation](http://massapi.com/class/pb/PBEParameterSpec.html), i understand that if you want to create a AES secret key you need to feed the algorithm with an at least 128 bit of a key.

```
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
```

so to generate key why do you insist getting the 128 bits from the PBE key, instead you can use

```
byte[] key = (Password+Username).getBytes("UTF-8"); // depends on your implementation
MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
key = sha.digest(key);
key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); // AES uses 16 byte of key as a parameter (?)
```

you can also use the PBE key to feed SHA and get the bytes in that way.  Okey let's turn to your problem, here is a full working code from my security folder, i remember this worked for me, please feel free to ask any questions. In the code below, if you check you'll see that the key is generated using the **pbeKeySpec**  however when i review the code, i cannot see what's your fault though.

```
public void testPBEWithSHA1AndAES() throws Exception {
        String password = "test";
        String message = "Hello World!";

        byte[] salt = { (byte) 0xc7, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0x21, (byte) 0x8c,
                (byte) 0x7e, (byte) 0xc8, (byte) 0xee, (byte) 0x99 };
        byte[] iv = { (byte) 0xc7, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0x21, (byte) 0x8c,
                (byte) 0x7e, (byte) 0xc8, (byte) 0xee, (byte) 0x99,
                (byte) 0xc7, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0x21, (byte) 0x8c,
                (byte) 0x7e, (byte) 0xc8, (byte) 0xee, (byte) 0x99 };

        int count = 1024;
        // int keyLength = 256;
        int keyLength = 128;

        String cipherAlgorithm = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
        String secretKeyAlgorithm = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";
        SecretKeyFactory keyFac = SecretKeyFactory
                .getInstance(secretKeyAlgorithm);
        PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt,
                count, keyLength);
        SecretKey tmp = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
        Cipher ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherAlgorithm);
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

        // decrypt
        keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(secretKeyAlgorithm);
        pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, count,
                keyLength);
        tmp = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
        secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
        // AlgorithmParameters params = ecipher.getParameters();
        // byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
        Cipher dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherAlgorithm);
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

        byte[] encrypted = ecipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
        byte[] decrypted = dcipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        assertEquals(message, new String(decrypted));

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        CipherOutputStream cipherOut = new CipherOutputStream(out, ecipher);
        cipherOut.write(message.getBytes());
        StreamUtils.closeQuietly(cipherOut);
        byte[] enc = out.toByteArray();

        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(enc);
        CipherInputStream cipherIn = new CipherInputStream(in, dcipher);
        ByteArrayOutputStream dec = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        StreamUtils.copy(cipherIn, dec);
        assertEquals(message, new String(dec.toByteArray()));
    }
```

Comment: this can run, however, tmp.getEncoded() always return the same value which is equals to your password, as I mentioned in my question, and no matter what the salt is.